# Mapping to Swift Object issue showing nil using Alamofire ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, json, swift2, alamofire, objectmapper

I m new to iOS and Swift development environment. I was trying to use Alamofire for pulling JSON and AlamofireObjectMapper for Mapping the retrieved JSON collections back to my Swift Object.

The issue is I m able to fetch the JSON thru Alamofire request and the count is shown, but the mapping part seems to be showing nil. Is something I had been missed out . Appreciate help.

## Model Class

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import ObjectMapper

class BranchObjectMapper : Mappable {
    // MARK: Properties
    var id: Int?
    var cityId: Int?
    var areaId: Int?
    var name: String?
    var nameAr: String?
    var branchAddr: String?
    var branchAddr2: String?
    var location: CLLocation?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id     <- map["id"]
        cityId    <- map["cityId"]
        areaId  <- map["areaId"]
        name  <- map["name"]
        nameAr  <- map["nameAr"]
        branchAddr  <- map["branchAddr"]
        branchAddr2  <- map["branchAddr2"]
        location  <- map["location"]
    }

}
```

Request part in `viewDidLoad()`

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, UrlEndpoints.branchUrl()).responseArray { (response: Response<[BranchObjectMapper], NSError>) in

    self.branchList = response.result.value!

    print(self.branchList.count) // count is correct

    for branch in self.branchList {      
        print(branch.id) // prints nil
        print(branch.id) // prints nil
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

The complete JSON response looks like below. Have constructed only needed ones in Model.

> [{"Id":"16","areaId":"17","name":"Al Aqiq”,”cityId”:4”,”Zip":"","nameAr":"\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0645","branchAddr":"test","branchAddr2":"test"Latitude":"24.60425","Longitude":"46.629631","cityId":"1"}]

Comment: Can you add the JSON please?

Comment: Your JSON response has the property "Id" and in your mapper class it is "id" (lowercase).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i think you are missing the right documentation of ObjectMapper lib.
Check this [Github ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#the-basics).

These are the types supported by the lib:

- `Int`
- `Bool`
- `Double`
- `Float`
- `String`
- `RawRepresentable` (Enums)
- `Array<AnyObject>`
- `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`
- `Object<T: Mappable>`
- `Array<T: Mappable>`
- `Array<Array<T: Mappable>>`
- `Set<T: Mappable>`
- `Dictionary<String, T: Mappable>`
- `Dictionary<String, Array<T:Mappable>>`
- Optionals of all the above
- Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals    of the above

So, if you are trying to map an Object not in that list, the result is `nil`.

In your case is `var location: CLLocation?`.

If you need to map CLLocation Object, one way is to map a CustomCLLocation with all properties as follows:
JSON(i don't know your Json, this is an example)

```
"location":{
    "long": 43.666,
    "lat": 73.4
}
```

Swift: create another file "CustomCLLocation" for example like the first one but for mapping CLLocation with your Json

```
var latitude: Double?
var longitude: Double?

required init?(_ map: Map) {
mapping(map)

}
func mapping(map: Map) {

   longitude <- map["long"]
   latitude <- map["lat"]
}
```

and now, you can map an "fake" CLLocation Object:
    var location: CustomCLLocation?

Then if you want a really CLLocation. just create an Simply Extension like that(add it in the CustomCLLocation file):

```
extension CLLocation {
     public class func createFromCustomCLLocation(custom: CustomCLLocation) -> CLLocation {
         return self.init(custom.latitude,custom.longitude)
     }
}
```

Using the conversion:

```
var locationCLL = CLLocation.createFromCustomCLLocation(location) // now is a CLLocation
```

## Edited: Alamofire Request

I have the same request on my app with the last version of AlamofireObjectMapper for ios 8.0 +

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, UrlEndpoints.branchUrl()).responseArray { (response: [BranchObjectMapper]?, error : ErrorType?) in
    if(error != nil) {
        print(error)
    }else{
        print("data downloaded")


        if let response = response {
            branchList(response)
            for branch in self.branchList {
                print(branch.id)
                print(branch.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I had removed CLLocation from the Mapping to check whether its due to the same. But what I had observed is all of the other fields also shows nil. Really appreciate your valuable comments.

Comment: I've edited my ask, just check the new Alamofire request.

Comment: Good because it is working. But, it is not a good solution since you always have to deal with conversion everywhere. For ex: you receive a CLLocation from your CoreLocation manager and you want to save it, then you do the conversion. Same goes all the time and lead to lot of duplicate codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems with mapping String and Int variables, it's because you forgot to add `dynamic` before `var`.

**Example:** `dynamic var id : Int?`